# Saving the same workbook with different name using button in 2 different tabs

Tags: excel, vba, save

maybe someone can tell what is wrong with my code.

It works works. However, it does not save the way I need. I have this workbook with various tabs and in 2 of this tabs I have a button "Save File" (with almost the same, changing few things as the name that the file is supposed to be saved e.g. ) `ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=savePath & "\Desktop\Investigations\" & CompanyName & " " & today & ".xls"` and `ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=savePath & "\Desktop\Investigations\" & CompanyName & " " & today & " (Level 2)" & ".xls"`

My issue is if the button on tab2 is saving the excel file on the top of already exists file. 
I need it to save a new excel file and not on the top of already exists. eg. the button on tab1 will save the file as **Alert +date**, the button on tab2 need to save a New file with the name **Alert + date + (Level 2)**.

My code for the tab Alert & date & (Level 2) is :

```
Sub Save_Level_2_File()

If ClientReview.Visible = True Then
Set Client = ClientReview

Else

 For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name Like "Client Review*" Then
     Set Client = ws

     End If
 Next ws
End If

If Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path = Environ("userprofile") & "\Desktop\Investigations" Then
 ActiveWorkbook.Save

End If

    Dim today As String
    Dim savePath As String
    Dim CompanyName As String
    Dim UserName As String

        Alert1.Activate
        today = Format(Date, "MM.DD.YYYY")
        Range("B4").Value = today

            With Range("B4")
                .Font.Color = .Interior.Color
            End With

UserName = Application.UserName
Alert1.Visible = xlSheetVisible
Alert1.Activate
Range("C1").Value = UserName
 Alert1.Name = "Alert " & today & " (Level 2)" 

If Len(Dir(savePath & "\Desktop\Investigations", vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
   MkDir (savePath & "\Desktop\Investigations")
End If

 ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=savePath & "\Desktop\Investigations\" & CompanyName & " " & today & " (Level 2)" & ".xls"

Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Where exactly should I change for the "Save File button" to save the same excel file as a new file with different name and not save on the top of the existing file?

PS: the change on the code need to be on the tab2, the tab that will save the name as **Alert & date of the day & (Level 2)** because this file will have all the information of previous file plus new information on itself tab before saving.

Comment: a little confusing to me... you may be more descriptive with what's worng with your code: what is it actually doing that's not right and in which cases?

Comment: @HTH I am not sure what is wrong. I need it to save a new excel file and not on the top of already exists. eg. the button on tab1 will save the file as **Alert +date**, the button on tab2 need to save a New file with the name **Alert + date + (Level 2).**

Comment: and what is button on tab2 doing actually?

Comment: It is saving on the top of the file that already exists as an update.

Comment: so you need to use tab 2 button more the once in the same date, don't you?

Comment: @HTH the code is bigger, however I put here the part that does the saving, because the code does something previous saving like correcting the clients name and checking for spelling etc. _I can edit the post and put the full code if it would help_.

Comment: I only need the answer to my question

Comment: yes, the tab2 will have the previous tabs plus the change the excel user will make on the tab2 sheet and save everything as a new document and the name need to change as it will have more information then previous. eg tab1 button will save as  **CDSS 03.31.2020** and tab2 button as **CDSS 03.31.2020 (Level 2)**.

Comment: ok, but that is what your last line of code is doing.

Comment: not really, it saves on the top of existing file eg. **CDSS 03.31.2020** it will have a new version of this file with the information of tab2 sheet, but on the top of the file with the same name.

Comment: so is it overwriting? or what

Comment: I dont know,  how I should change the code. It is saving on the top of the file already exists in the destination folder, but I need to it  to save as a new excel file

Comment: maybe it would be possible to add a line saying it should save as a new excel file

Comment: @HTH even if the the files will be saved in different day the button on tab2 will save it on the top of the previous file and even the date will not be changed e.g **CDSS 03.31.2020** and I use the tab2 button to save today it should save as **_CDSS 04.02.2020 (level 2)_**, however, it will save as CDSS 03.31.2020 but new version (just save on top of it).

Comment: see if my answer catches the mouse; not so sure though: in case leave comments there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's the code I could get out of your comments

```
Sub Save_Level_2_File()


    Dim Client As Worksheet, ClientReview As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet

    If ClientReview.Visible Then
        Set Client = ClientReview
    Else
        For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            If ws.Name Like "Client Review*" Then
                Set Client = ws
                Exit For
            End If
        Next ws
    End If

    If Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path = Environ("userprofile") & "\Desktop\Investigations" Then ActiveWorkbook.Save ' <-- this will overwrite previous version


    Dim today As String
    Dim savePath As String
    Dim companyName As String
    Dim userName As String
    Dim Alert1 As Worksheet

    today = Format(Date, "MM.DD.YYYY")
    userName = Application.userName
    With Alert1
        With .Range("B4")
            .Value = today
            .Font.Color = .Interior.Color
        End With

        .Visible = xlSheetVisible
        .Range("C1").Value = userName
        .Name = "Alert " & today & " (Level 2)"
    End With

    If Len(Dir(savePath & "\Desktop\Investigations", vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir (savePath & "\Desktop\Investigations")


    '------------
    Dim fullName As String
    fullName = savePath & "\Desktop\Investigations\" & companyName & " " & today & " (Level 2)" & ".xls"

    If Dir(fullName) <> vbNullString Then fullName = savePath & "\Desktop\Investigations\" & companyName & " " & today & " (Level 2)" & Format(Time, "hhmmss") & ".xls"

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=fullName
    '------------


End Sub
```

where I

- warned you about a line that is sistematically overwriting `ThisWorkbook`
- added the last code block (that enclosed in between "------------" comment lines) take care of addimg a hourstamp should a "...Level2" file already be in place
- made some revisions in other parts to have (possibly) a more readable efficent and reusable code

Comment: Thank you, I am trying it right now.
In the line `if ClientReview.Visible then` I am getting a error: Run-time '91' object variable or with block variable not set.

Comment: It means that you have to `Set ClientReview = …` but I don't have clues about what other then it is possibly a worksheet. But that part of code I left as it was before so if your code worked before it has to work again.

Comment: Thank you, it is great. put the names I need and Everything is working. it saved with the hours as well (so I will take it of, because I dont need it).